# Can't get key - angularfire2

Tags: angularfire2

Hello I am using angularfire2 + firebase into my ionic3 app, I am tryng to get key (for example: C0u7DXjuejQjfCBHBnwL9xK3TCi1) but can't

not working:

```
<li *ngFor="let client of clients | async">
   {{client.key}}
</li>
```

I tired also `client.$key` but not working..

but I am getting values good. for example:

```
<li *ngFor="let client of clients | async">
   {{client.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: any code snipet for provider? `valueChanges()` doesn't include rtdb object  key(firestore document id).

Comment: use `.snapshotChanges()` to get data. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291644/angular-firebase-5-objects-keys-not-being-displayed-so-cant-delete/47291970#47291970)