# Get $key object realtime database Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am implementing dynamic routes in Realtime Database of Firebase based on the ID or `$key` of each object. What I want is to get the ID and I can not find the way, I get the value `undefinied`. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

**portafolio.component.html**

```
<div class="container my-5">
<h1>Portafolio</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let proyecto of proyectos | async">
        <div class="card my-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ proyecto.titulo }}</h4>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/portafolio', proyecto.$key]">Ver detalles</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**portafolio.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-portafolio',
  templateUrl: './portafolio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portafolio.component.scss']
})
export class PortafolioComponent implements OnInit {

  proyectos: any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.proyectos = this.db.list('proyectos').valueChanges();

  }

}
```

proyecto.ts

```
export interface Proyecto {
$key?: string;
titulo?: string;
destacado?: string;
descripcion?: string;}
```

Comment: You need to use `snapshotChanges` to get the key. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291644/angular-firebase-5-objects-keys-not-being-displayed-so-cant-delete/47291970#47291970)

Comment: Excellent worked for me with `snapshotChanges ()`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Hareesh for sharing the related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291970/8312532

This worked for me:

portafolio.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";



@Component({
  selector: 'app-portafolio',
  templateUrl: './portafolio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portafolio.component.scss']
})
export class PortafolioComponent implements OnInit {

  todosProyectos: AngularFireList<any>;
  proyectos: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this. todosProyectos = this.db.list('proyectos');

    this.proyectos = this.todosProyectos.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });


  }

}
```

portafolio.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
<h1>Portafolio</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let proyecto of proyectos | async">
        <div class="card my-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ proyecto.titulo }}</h4>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/portafolio', proyecto.key]">Ver detalles</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the square bracket to access the object property, `proyecto['$key']`

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/portafolio', proyecto['$key']]">Ver detalles</a>
```

Comment: are you sure? I'm still coming out `undefined`

Comment: post the `proyecto` object

Comment: I have included the project project.ts

Comment: print `{{ proyecto }}` in the html and post the result

Comment: the result is `[object Object]`

Comment: use `{{ proyecto | json}}`

Comment: `{ "descripcion": "test7", "destacado": "test7", "titulo": "test7" }`

Comment: there is no property called `$key` make sure you assign value to `$key` property

Comment: What do I do when creating that object? I was testing including `itemsRef.push({ $key: this.$key, titulo: this.titulo, destacado: this.destacado, descripcion: this.descripcion, }); ` but nothing records me.

Comment: make sure `this.$key` is not empty