# Unable to fetch $key from firebase in Angular5 template

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I am making a form in **Angular5** using **firebase** in backend. The form contains few input fields and a dropdown.

I'm able to populate values ({{ c.name }}) in dropdown options but value attribute of option is coming empty which I'm trying to populate using **c.$key**.

Below is the HTML part:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
    <!-- other input fields here -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key"> 
            {{ c.name }} 
          </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my component:

```
import { CategoryService } from './../../category.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  save(product) {
    console.log(product);
  }

}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

    @Injectable()
    export class CategoryService {

      constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

      getCategories() {
        return this.db.list('/categories', ref => ref.orderByChild('name')).valueChanges();
      }
    }
```

I'm printing value of form json on console. The value of category is coming undefined.

```
{title: "Title", price: 10, category: "undefined", imageUrl: "xyz"}
```

Please guide me what am I missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular FIrebase 5 objects keys not being displayed. So can't delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291644/angular-firebase-5-objects-keys-not-being-displayed-so-cant-delete)

Comment: @R.Richards thanks. It was helpful. I fetched key using **c.key** and did below changes in service method:


`
getCategories() {
    return this.db.list('/categories', ref => ref.orderByChild('name'))
      .snapshotChanges().map(categories => {
        return categories.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
      });
  }`

Comment: I do the same. Seems to work well for what is needed. Glad you found the link helpful. I think I used that same answer when I ran across this issue the first time.

Answer (score 1):

`$key` has been deprecated. Use `snapshotChanges()` instead.

**category.service.ts**

```
getCategories() {
    return this.db
        .list('/categories', (ref) => ref.orderByChild('name'))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
        map((actions) => {
            return actions.map((action) => ({
                key: action.key,
                val: action.payload.val(),
            }));
        }));

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
    {{ c.val.name }}
</option>
```