# How to get keys from firebase database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

l have following data structure:

[image]

l am trying to get multiple keys in firebase database using angularfire2 . The first key is user uid and the second key is unique keys . My code below is working fine , but l am unable to get both keys for each data . l am getting only UNIQUE key of " hold data "without User id key .

my Code

```
ordersstatus : AngularFireList<any>;
 ngOnInit() {

    this.ordersstatus =  this.af.list("/orders")
this.ordersstatus .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(changes =>
      changes.map(c => ({ $key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
    )
  ).subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.ordersstatus = data

    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

Html

```
       <ng-container  *ngFor="let a of ordersstatus; let i=index">              
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of a | keyvalue">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><a (click)="details(item,a)" ></i></a></td> <---- add keys to button 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

any idea how to get both keys " user id  key"  and " UNIQE key " of data please ?

Comment: The `valueChanges` stream only gets the **value** of each node, and not its key. If you also want the keys, you'll have to use the `snapshotChanged` stream. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291644/angular-firebase-5-objects-keys-not-being-displayed-so-cant-delete/47291970#47291970

Comment: i believe it is not same ! because he already has course/ then key . l have user key then UNIQE key .

Comment: my problem is with UNIQE key not with user key